# How to detect modules enabled incorrectly?

Tags: 7

If some errors occurs in the process of enabling modules (WSOD due to OOM and others), it happens that the modules are shown as enabled. But in such cases the features of those modules are broken since the enabling/installing of the modules were not completely run.

How do I detect such modules state without re-enabling every single module?

Update: Obviously logs can be disabled/cleared/lost, don't mention them please.

Comment: This is a totally legit question and should be reopened. It is totally clear what the user asks: what modules are in such a state where `module_enable` started but didn't finish. The answer is: this can't be done in general if watchdog is pruned because `drupal_set_installed_schema_version` runs before `hook_install` and `hook_enable`. If you want, write a module which logs to a safe place in a `hook_modules_enabled` implementation (last to run) and compare that with the state of the module in `{system}`. If the `schema_version` is > -1 but it's not in your special log you have a broken module

Comment: Also, I thought we have a voting system for closing questions and ♦ users shouldn't just close a question on whim? I have heard complaints in the past that Drupal SE is not in line with "the Drupal community is welcoming" philosophy and I'm not particularly happy to see it in action. [Escalating](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/how-to-marry-the-conflicting-philosophies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that it depends on each module. When enabled, a module sets up its environment (create tables, variables, declare URL, etc) but this environment is not declared explicitly so you can't automatically check that the module has been installed correctly.

You may check the install file for the modules's scheme (tables defined by the module) and the hook_enable to see what tasks needs the module when is enabled.

I think best way is to uninstall modules and try to install them again, so all modules's environent are cleared when unisntalling and set up again when enabled again.

Using drush this tasks is very easy and handy.

Ah, and try to clear caches to see if modules works, but you won't be sure modules installed correctly...

Comment: The first paragraph of this is the only possible answer to the question. There's no one single 'state' that defines when a module is 'successfully' enabled or not. Drupal checks the `status` column in the system table to see if it's been enabled, but it cannot detect when a module has failed to install because of a memory timeout/fatal error, because such a thing can't be strictly defined. Even if it _could_ be strictly defined, Drupal doesn't.

Comment: Well, maybe. Now I'm wondering why does Drupal set it to enabled before actually enabling.

Comment: Are you positive that's what it does? Don't forget, there are **3** states a module can be in: disabled, installed and enabled, and various hooks available for modules to make changes at any of those states

Comment: Totally positive. Regardless of the name. Enabled modules must be installed. Isn't that reasonable?

Comment: May be Drupal could add a new state, installing, that changes to installed when all task are done. But this introduce more complexity in system (module has more state to check, more posibilities) and it doesn't really resolve a big issue. Half installed modules only happens when a server error occurs (PHP memory, time exceeded and so on, errors that should not happen in aproduction environment) or bad behaviored or development modules (again, shoud not happen in production). If you reaslly think is a needed functionality you can fill a bug report in the core issue queue.

Comment: Yes, I will do that when I'll find some time to check 8.x, thanks, tunic. IMHO it will reduce debugging/support complexity far more.

Comment: @tunic Instead of a new state in the system table, there could be a separate table that keeps track of modules that are currently installing, and maybe other operations that are "in progress".

Answer (score 0):

You should check the dblog at /admin/reports/dblog after such situation. You can also see error_log file in the Drupal root installation folder.

Comment: `dblog` can be disabled or cleared. I've never seen `error_log` in Drupal root. Apache logs also can be empty.

Comment: Keep it enabled when do such activity.

Comment: There are situations when you get a site in already broken state, you know.

Comment: Please change your question accordingly. Don't change it here. Re-edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `drush`, you can check if module is enabled by:

```
drush pm-list | grep foo
```

If the installation process stops, try:

1. Refreshing the page again (with POST-ing the data again)
2. Enable module one of each time.
3. Clear caches (`drush -y cc all`).
4. Check the `.install` file from the module directory to see what tables it should create and other data during the installation. If the installation is broken, re-install it (`drush -y dre` when using Devel).